# XSLT merge rows from adjacent HTML tables, of same structure, in a single table

Tags: xslt, merge, html-table, rows

I am new to XSLT and I have the requirement of bringing all rows of adjacent HTML tables, having the same structure, in a single table, simply by appending all rows of following tables in the first table encountered:

## Input:

```
<div>
<span class="title">sample</span>
<br/>
    some text node1
    <br/>
    some text node2
<p/>
<table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L1:</td>
       <td>C1</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <p/>
 <span class="section">Section1</span>
<p/>
<table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L2:</td>
       <td>C2</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 <table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L3:</td>
       <td>C3</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
    <table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L4:</td>
       <td>C4</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
    <span class="section">Section2</span>
<p/>
    <table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L5:</td>
       <td>C5</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
    <table class="class2">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L6:</td>
      <td>C6</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The resulting output, should merge adjacent tables with @class="class1".

## Output:

```
<div>
<span class="title">sample</span>
<br/>
    some text node1
    <br/>
    some text node2
<p/>
<table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L1:</td>
       <td>C1</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
<p/>
<span class="section">Section1</span>
<p/>
<table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L2:</td>
       <td>C2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>L3:</td>
       <td>C3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>L4:</td>
      <td>C4</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <span class="section">Section1</span>
<p/>
<table class="class1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>L5:</td>
       <td>C5</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
    <table class="class2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>L6:</td>
      <td>C6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Any ideas how this can be realized? I have been trying to do this using group-adjacent, but I'm not getting the intended result, and I don't know what's missing me.

***- Edit:***

here is my attempt (**NOT WORKING PROPERLY**).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[@class='class1']">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::table])">
<xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@class='class1'" />
    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1]/@class='class1'" >
         <table class="class1">
           <tbody>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody/*"/>
           <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:if test="self::table[@class='class1']">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody/*"/>
             </xsl:if> 
           </xsl:for-each>
           </tbody>
          </table>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
```

**NOTE**
If possible help me do that both in XSLT1.0, enhancing my attempt, and/or XSLT2.0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the following to your question: **1** Your attempted XSLT code (even if it does not work - that's precisely the point of asking here) **2** a clarification of what exactly you mean by "I'm not getting the intended result".

Comment: *"I have been trying to do this using group-adjacent"* Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor, then?

Comment: well, I've tried this using both XSLT1.0 with following-siblings and XSLT2.0. I'm open to both...

Comment: @MathiasMüller: I have editted to include my attempt, using XSLT1.0, which seems now to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body | div"><!-- need to list other container elements here -->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node() except text()[not(normalize-space())]" group-adjacent="boolean(self::table[@class = 'class1'])">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
          <table class="{@class}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="thead"/>
            <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/tbody/tr"/>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is a correction of the first version which should ensure that all text nodes containing more than white space are also copied. But it assumes that between those tables you want to group there is solely white space.

Comment: with the select="*" I am loosing text nodes at the same level as the tables being grouped (not in the example above). Is there any way around this?

Comment: It is more difficult dealing with mixed contents, please edit your question to show samples with text nodes between tables and show us the result you want. Basically we need to use `select="node()"` and then adjust the grouping, depending on what you want to do with text nodes between tables.

Comment: Thanks. Example and expected output have been edited!

Comment: @Dieter.G, I have slightly changed the code to use `select="node() except text()[not(normalize-space())]"` to allow the processing of non white space text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Another version using XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::table[@class='class1'])">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[@class='class1'] and current-group()[2]">
                    <table class="{@class}">
                        <tbody>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/descendant::tr"/>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::table[@class='class2'])">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="current-group()[@class='class2'] and current-group()[2]">
                                <table class="{@class}">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/descendant::tr"/>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

not to disappoint you this time, there was a small change done:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="key" match="table[@class = following::*[1][local-name() = 'table']/@class or @class = preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name() = 'table']/@class]" use="@class"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[not(@class = following::*[1][local-name() = 'table']/@class or @class = preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name() = 'table']/@class)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="table[@class = following::*[1][local-name() = 'table']/@class or @class = preceding-sibling::*[1][local-name() = 'table']/@class]"/>

<xsl:template match="table[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key', @class)[1])]">
    <table class="{@class}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('key', @class)/tbody"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: They xsl:key declaration was wrong to select the non-adjacent table elements. Have corrected it in the new post

Comment: Tested, and worked as supposed!! Thank you very much!