# XSL Transformation <Para> content missing while row merge

Tags: xslt

INPUT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TABLE>
<THEAD>
    <ROW id="rh">
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >A</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >B</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >C</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >D</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >F</Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>


</THEAD>
<TBODY editable="T">
    <ROW id="r1">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para >11</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para >12</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >13</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >14</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>

    <ROW id="r2">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >23</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >24</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="T"  rowspan="2" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

OUTPUT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <TABLE>
<THEAD>
    <ROW id="rh">
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >A</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >B</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >C</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >D</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >F</Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>


    </THEAD>
    <TBODY editable="T">
    <ROW id="r1">
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >11</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >12</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >13</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >14</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan=1" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>

    <ROW id="r2">
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >11</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >12</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >23</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para >24</Para>
        </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"  rowspan="1" >
            <Para ></Para>
        </CELL>
    </ROW>
</TBODY>
    </TABLE>
```

While transforming the input XML with this transformation XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    version="1.0">

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CELL">
<CELL rowmerged="F" rowspan="1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</CELL>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Para[not(normalize-space())][../@rowmerged='T']">
<xsl:variable name="cellnum" select="count(../preceding-sibling::CELL) + 1" />
<xsl:variable name="matchingCells" select="
    ../../preceding-sibling::ROW/CELL[$cellnum]/Para" />
<xsl:copy-of select="$matchingCells[normalize-space()][last()]" />
 </xsl:template>
```

The unvalued tag  is not replaced with the exact location and hence returns

```
<CELL>
 Para not found in OUTPUTXML
</CELL>
```

We generated output but the EMPTY Para(`<Para>`) content is missing while row merge is happening.

Kindly help me in achieving this and I'm new to this XSLT.
Rule: for merged rows: copy content of primary merged cell to other cells in merged rows. Could you please help me out in this scenario. I am new to xslt.

Comment: Post your XSLT code (and escape angle bracket tags with leading and trailing "`" to mark them as code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve elements without text node, you should do something like this:

```
<Para>
    <xsl:value-of select="$matchingCells[normalize-space()][last()]"/>
</Para>
```

Your template is almost unreadable. Why to go all this trouble:

```
Para[not(normalize-space())][../@rowmerged='T']
```

It would be more helpful if you'll explain what you want to get more clearly.

Comment: See the above XSL defines how to merge both the rows and its working fine no problem.

Comment: See the above XSL defines how to merge both the rows and its working fine no problem. Before merge if CELL has empty Para then , after merging the CELL is empty and the previously declared Para with attributes doesn't exists.